# Isn't a valid edit behavior to provide module links for answers?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Have a look at my [suggested Edit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31059); it got rejected. It seems to be minor, but I believe that providing resource links, such as links to project pages for the modules hosted on Drupal.org, is helpful, especially for answers. In that way, the user who asked the question, but also future readers, doesn't need to search for that module.

Is this a valid way to edit answers?

Comment: Linking to project page is completely fine!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't control what all reviewers do, but personally, I will almost always approve edits that just link out to the relevant modules.

Ideally, you should also do some cleanup, too, if the post needs it.

In that particular edit, I would have also linked Nice Menus.

Comment: Thanks MPD. Yes I always do cleanups along with my edits. BTW I provided resource link for jQuery Update module only because there is no priority (in post) for Nice Menus module. So I didn't provide a link for that. :)

Answer (score 4):

Providing links to the project pages is indeed a valid edit, but it should not be the only edit, when there are more edits to do. The reason is that suggested edit are reviewed, and the suggested edit should be worth the time took to review it.

I would have edited the post as follows:

> I am using Nice Menus to build the menu for large screen rendering, which installs a version of bgiframe.js that is not compatible with the latest version of jQuery. Since I am using the [jQuery Update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update)  module that brings jQuery up to the latest version, the Nice Menus module throws errors.
>
> The solution is to drop the jQuery version back to 1.7.